# static ip in NetworkManager but ifconfig does not show the ip (ubuntustudio 14.04)

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, ifconfig, static-ip

i am running `ubuntustudio 14.04`.

I have a development setup where my pc has 2 `NICs` one of which connects to the internet and acquires dhcp ip from the router, while the other (eth1) is used to connect development boards etc. Now, on eth1 I have a dhcp server running for that "development intranet" and I want to have a static ip address on this interface.

The problem is that dhcp server fails to start executing and the reason is that `eth1` does not have the ip that I have set through the `NetworkManager`. Checking with ifconfig:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 10:fe:ed:05:99:21  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I have done the following:

- `sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` switched `managed` to `true`.
- tried through `NetworkManager` to setup [image] eth1, but it is disabled as you can see.
- I went on to create a new interface based on `eth1`, the one you see named as `Ethernet Connection 1`.
  [image]

the system does not get ipaddress through network manager, whether I have the cable unplugged, or plugs. By the way, I strongly prefer the former.

I wonder if i'll make my life more difficult if I disable network manager altogether and just write the ipaddress in `/etc/network/interfaces/ file. It is a desktop after all.

Have I missed something in order to make `NetworkManager` assign the static ip permanently from boot to shutdoown??

thank you

Answer (score 0):

NetworkManager will override dhcp settings, overwriting resolv.conf even if you've configured DNS in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf, e.g. causing DNS to first search the local domain, which may have to time out before DNS resolution continues causing lengthy DNS resolution times.

Test this:

Uninstall it

```
sudo su
apt-get remove --purge networkmanager*
```

Configure the interface manually

```
sudo su 
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Example file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
    allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
    iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.29.19
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.29.0
        broadcast 192.168.29.255
      ##gateway 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: hi there, I do not refer to dhcp client anywhere, nor `resolv.conf`. still you basically advice (even though not tell explicitly) to remove `networkManager`.  will that brake my desktop's network connections in anyway I have not thought of ?